# How to call subsequent request using j_security_check

Tags: java

How to call subsequent requests using j_security_check, I have followed below code but it's not working .

```
String url = "https://myhost/jsp/j_security_check?j_username=myuser&j_password=mypassword";
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new
     URL(url).openConnection();     
    if (connection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
        String cookie = connection.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie").split(";", 2)[0];
        url = "https://myhost/getusers";
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);                
        connection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        try (BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()))) {
            String result = buffer.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
            System.out.println(result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
    }
```

Can anyone help me on it.

Comment: Please state out what your problem is in detail.

Comment: I want to use invoke my subsequent REST call's by using cookie, i need some sample program in java,I have added my sample code but it is not working, it is giving some html content in the response